# Rails Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In routes.rb I have:

```
get "survey/show" => "survey#show"
post "survey/step_2" => "survey#step_2"
post "survey/step_3" => "survey#step_3"
```

And in step_2.html.erb I have:

```
<%= form_for @result, :url => { :controller => 'survey', :action => 'step_3' } do |f| %>
```

And in survey_controller.rb I have:

```
def step_2
@result = Result.new(params[:result])

if @result.save
    session[:result_id] = @result.id
    render :action => "step_2"
else
    render :action => "show"
end
end

def step_3
@result = Result.find(session[:result_id])

if @result.update_attributes(params[:result])
    render :action => "step_3"
else
    render :action => "step_2"
end
end
```

And when I submit the form on step_2 I get the following error:
`No route matches "/survey/step_3"`

Comment: are you sure the request you are making is a post request. By your route definition, get requests to survey/step_3 will be rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Rails form_for method may be making that a PUT request, since the @result object has an id. I believe you should change your form_for line to:

<%= form_for @result, 
             :url => { :controller => 'survey', :action => 'step_3' },
             :html => { :method => :post} do |f| %>

or change the route type to `put` in routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

You have to use match.

```
match 'survey/step_3' => 'survey#step_3', :via => 'post'
```

I might be wrong about the :via, but it's something like that.